# Nested JSON appsetting substitution not working in microsoft/variable-substitution

Tags: c#, .net, github, github-actions, appsettings

I am trying to replace a nested JSON object in the app setting.

Below is the expectation:

Before replacement:

```json
{    
    "externalapp": ""    
}
```

After replacement:

```json
{
    "externalapp": {
        "url":"https://external.com",
        "cleintid": "cid",
        "secret":"client secret"
    }
}
```

`externalapp` JSON ({..} including braces) is stored as a secret in GitHub environments and referenced during the workflow run.
But the problem is that the replaced JSON is appearing as a string.

Below is the actual output:

```json
"externalapp":
    "{\n
    \"url\":\"https://external.com", \n
    \"clientid\": \"cid", \n
    \"secret\":\"client secret" \n
    \n}"
```

Any idea how to get rid of these additional characters (`\n`, `\`,`"`)?

Please find the workflow code:

```yaml
- name: Update Dynamics URL
  uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1 
  with:
    files: 'appsettings.json'
  env:
    externalapp: ${{ secrets.EXTERNAL_APP }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question showing the step where you configure it from that secret. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem , workflow code updated in the question.

Comment: Thanks! That `externalapp` without quotes is invalid. Are you sure it's the same in your `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: quotes updated. The problem is , value of externalapp which generated after workflows run.

Comment: Your use case is different. You want a JSON object to be replaced/expanded as valid JSON against a key. [`microsoft/variable-substitution`](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution) action doesn't seem to be doing that. It substitute the existing value with a new one from the env based on its JSON key. You can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead as mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712857/7670262) below.

Comment: Does the variables required to start the c# application or is for devops issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that [`jobs.<job_id>.steps\[*\].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv) loads your secret as a JSON string, which will replace your line breaks with `\n` and escape all your JSON key/values quotes with `\"`.

If you don't have another reason to use [`microsoft/variable-substitution`](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution), just use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to update your object. For example:

```
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - shell: bash
        run: |
          echo '{ "externalapp": ""  }' > appsettings.json
      - name: Replace secret
        shell: bash
        run: |
           cat appsettings.json | jq --argjson my_secret $MY_SECRET '.externalapp = $my_secret' > newfile.json
        env: 
          # In your case it would be:  ${{ secrets.EXTERNAL_APP }}
          MY_SECRET: '{ "url":"https://external.com", "cleintid": "cid", "secret":"client secret" }'
```

Comment: The newlines are already there and are retained. I suspect that those `\"` seem to be caused by the JavaScript's [`JSON.stringity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution/blob/8c51fbdacd6eeb14b543a993adca02a7c07e6f27/src/variableSubstitution.ts#L46). You can experiment with `console.log(JSON.stringify({"k":"v"}));` and 
`console.log(JSON.stringify('{"k":"v",\n"x":"y"}'));`.

Comment: @Fcmam5 I have tried with jq but result was different format. It removes the double quotes from child props.  output was like  "{url:https://external.com, cleintid: cid, secret:client secret }"

Comment: How are you checking the output? And what's the format of your secret? is it inserted as a json object?

Comment: @Azeem - Thank you for the code reference. It helped me to identity the actual problem.

Comment: @kamilhussain: Isn't the above answer with `jq` working for you? That should resolve your issue. If it's not, please include what you tried and the respective output in your question under an UPDATE section. That'll be very helpful for others to identify the issue and suggest accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem The problem with json implementation of microsoft/variable-substitution. Here  in my appsetting , I am not passing any value to external app   "externalapp": "" , so it sets the type of value to be string. It is not considering type of dynamically passed secrets or env variables.

Comment: I have forked the repo and made changes for my project.

Comment: @Fcmam - I have tried with powershell script. It is giving error if I use --argjson argument

Comment: @kamilhussain: IIRC, that project has been archived. Not sure if they're accepting PRs anymore. Its last commit is from [Sep 2022](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution/commit/8c51fbdacd6eeb14b543a993adca02a7c07e6f27). If you plan to use your fork, it's all good. IMO, `jq` is good enough to do the job and it's preinstalled too.

Comment: its works If I use just --arg

Comment: @kamilhussain: That might be some version difference. IIRC, all GHA runners use the same version of `jq`. See the list of preinstalled software [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software). BTW, you should have included your workflow in your question to clarify that you're using a Windows runner with Powershell. For PowerShell, the env vars are like this `$ENV:MY_SECRET` so you need to adjust that command accordingly. Thanks!